# (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I'm using following query to read data from a mysql db:
setup:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='**', passwd='**', db='***')
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://***')

sql = 'show tables like "{}"'.format('aTable_' + '%')
```

option-1: this is OK

```
a1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
```

option-2: this will throw errors:
ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb.*exceptions.ProgrammingError) not enough arguments for format string
[SQL: show tables like "aTable*%" ]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

```
a1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)
```

what should I do if i want to use the second style(engine as the param)?

Comment: Did you try with some other query, a simple select or something trivial?

Comment: @luistm, for simple sql string it works on both connection and engine version

Answer (score 5):

Instead of passing values to SQL using string formatting, use placeholders:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://***')
sql = text('SHOW TABLES LIKE :pattern')
a1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine, params={'pattern': 'aTable_%'})
```

Using [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) allows you to use the named [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) regardless of your DB-API driver in use. Placeholders ensure that you, [or anyone else](https://xkcd.com/327/), don't accidentally inject unintended SQL to your query, for example by passing a string containing quotes as a value.

In this case the problem stems from the `%` character. If the MySQLdb DB-API driver's [`execute()`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L179) method is called without arguments, it will not attempt to use placeholders in the query. On the other hand it looks like SQLAlchemy is passing `execute()` an empty argument container, which triggers the code path that attempts to use the placeholders in the query string, which in the end—*after* converting the arguments to their SQL literal form—is done using %-formatting, and so the error "not enough arguments for format string":

```
In [4]: 'show tables like "aTable_%"' % ()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4f31bc6a7bb6> in <module>()
----> 1 'show tables like "aTable_%"' % ()

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: thank, after wrap the raw string into a sqlalchemy.text() object, it's OK to use the engine version, but failed on the connection version;  why this difference? and when should I use engine and when to use connection? from pandas.read_sql_query() doc it accepts both engine and connect.

Comment: `text()` is an SQLAlchemy construct, so you'd use it when you're using SQLAlchemy (engine). It will not work with a raw DB-API connection. And while `text()` escapes `%` even if you format the value directly to the raw SQL string manually, don't do that. Use placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on panda read_sql_query and faced below error:

```
ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) not enough arguments for format string[SQL: SELECT * FROM `alarms` 
                    WHERE 
                    (`Supplementary` NOT LIKE '%door%') 
                    AND 
                    ( `Supplementary` LIKE '%main%') 
                     )]
```

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

It solved the issue with **a double % sign** as below:

```
(`Supplementary` NOT LIKE '%%door%%') AND ( `Supplementary` LIKE '%%main%%')
```